# Ansible playbook: Requires sudo password

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-2.x

I am currently working with ansible and I want to automate dumping of my Remote DB and import the dumped file to my local DB. Now, I encountered some problem for using **sudo** to switch user.

**playbook.yml**

```
  ---
  - hosts: remoteserver
    vars:
      remote_db_name: dbname
      remote_filename: dbname_{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%m-%d-%Y') }}
      local_folder: /home/alde/database_backups/

    tasks:
      - name: Dump database
        become: yes
        become_user: postgres
        shell: pg_dump -d {{remote_db_name}} > "{{remote_filename}}"
```

when I try to run ***ansible-playbook playbook.yml*** it returns: ***"sudo: a password is required"***

[image]

---

**What I have tried so far.**

1) I tried  [this solution](https://www.callum-macdonald.com/2016/03/09/ansible-and-pam-ssh-agent-auth/) by adding sudo_flags.

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
sudo_flags = -H -S
```

then I got a different error when I execute my playbook: ***"Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "***

[image]

2) I increased the ***timeout*** up to 30.

3) I added the default remote user to sudoers file

It's strange because there's no password prompt when I try to access my remote server using ssh and switch from default_user to postgres using *sudo su - postgres*

---

- ansible 2.3.0.0
- Python 2.7
- Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Please do not post barely readable images when text would be enough. It's pretty clear from the error message that the system requires password for `sudo`. Why is there nothing in the question about the configuration and your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

The linked glossary says:

> The default is ‘-H -S -n’ which sets the HOME environment variable, prompts for passwords via STDIN, and avoids prompting the user for input of any kind. Note that ‘-n’ will conflict with using password-less sudo auth, such as pam_ssh_agent_auth. In some situations you may wish to add or remove flags, but in general most users will not need to change this setting::

So I think that trying the -n flag as well would at least change something since it seems like you've changed it to **waiting on authentication** rather than **there is no authentication** with your last modification.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to put the -n flag back but still the same.

Comment: It's possible that it has to do with the settings on your machine since it seems to be a display issue. Maybe run some code against your system to see what settings you have.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. what should I execute?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add your root user under the host.

```
 ---
  - hosts: remoteserver
    remote_user: root
    become: yes
    become_user: root
    become_method: sudo
    vars:
      remote_db_name: dbname
      remote_filename: dbname_{{ lookup('pipe', 'date +%m-%d-%Y') }}
      local_folder: /home/alde/database_backups/

    tasks:
      - name: Dump database
        become: yes
        become_user: postgres
        shell: pg_dump -d {{remote_db_name}} > "{{remote_filename}}"
```

You can try to add the line to `sudoer file` (sudo visudo)
`<ssh user> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` and test it, maybe something is wrong there.